# Python - Access object attributes as in a dictionary

Tags: python, object, dictionary

```
>>> my_object.name = 'stuff'
>>> my_str = 'name'
>>> my_object[my_str] # won't work because it's not a dictionary :)
```

How can I access to the fields of `my_object` defined on `my_str` ?

Comment: btw, this is totally valid in javascript

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
getattr(my_object, my_str)
```

Or, if you're not sure if the name exists as a key and want to provide a fallback instead of throwing an exception:

```
getattr(my_object, my_str, "Could not find anything")
```

[More on getattr.](https://web.archive.org/web/20200703234823/http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm)

Comment: What is the advantage against `myobject.__dict__[my_str]` ? better performance ?

Comment: Can I fall back on the standard "It's more Pythonic" answer? Also, tapping into the private __ variables comes with its own set of risks. What you're trying to do is what getattr and setattr are for.

Comment: Word of warning though - if you use dynamic attribute names you should either use `try:` or add `if hasattr(` before using `getattr` to make sure you're not trying to access something that's not there.

Comment: Huh? `getattr` does not throw an exception if the attribute doesn't exist. It's basically syntactic sugar for `if hasattr give me that else give me the default`.

Comment: To answer my own ignorance down the road that's because I was always passing a third argument for the default, e.g., `getattr(my_object, my_str, None)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide support for the `[]` operator for objects of your class by defining a small family of methods - [**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [**setitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__), principally.  See the next few entries in the docs for some others to implement, for full support.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myobject.__dict__[my_str]
'stuff'
```

Comment: Note that this breaks for properties, `__slots__` and `__getattr__/__getattribute__/__setattr__` overloads - and probably some other things.

Comment: Ok thank you for the info. Do you think `getattr(my_object, my_str)` is better for performance also ?

Comment: Performance is your least concern here. If it is, you could rewrite that part (i.e. the whole loop, to avoid many cross-language calls) in C, but you should have solid proof of an unacceptable slowdown before considering such optimizations.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the `__dict__`-approach in general. What will always work is

```
getattr(myobject, my_str)
```

If you want dict-like access, just define a class with an overloaded index-operator.